# поведение переменой в функции и with выражении

Tags: python, функции, область-видимости

как коректно создать "глобальную" переменую чтобы можно было нормально работать с `with`

```
    def get_all_urls(self):

        urls_list = list()

        with self.connect:
            sql = self.cursor.execute("SELECT url FROM urls;")
            urls_list = sql.fetchall()

        url_replace = lambda x: x[3:len(x)-4]

        return list(map(url_replace, urls_list))
```

результат программы :

```
[(), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), ()]
```

в итоге  в `with` выражении создается свой список  `urls_list` который не виден всей функции а  `urls_list` "глобальный" не используется и просто возвращается пустым
а функция должна возвращать список ссылок , так как же корректно использовать `urls_list`

Comment: Покажите, что у вас в `urls_list` получается. Полагаю там список кортежей и слайс работает с кортежем, а не со строкой. Надо что-то типа `x[0][3:len(x[0])-4]` брать тогда, но это чисто предположение.

Comment: да действительно , оказується дело в этом

Comment: Но ```urls_list``` я правильно использую ?

Comment: А насчёт глобальной переменной, лучше не использовать глобальные переменные. Хотите что-то передать вне функции - передавайте это через `return`

Comment: ну там глобальная в кавычках я просто думал что ```with```не принимает существующий ```url_list```а создает новый

Comment: `with` ограничивает область видимости только той переменной, с которой она работает. То, что вы делаете с остальными переменными внутри блока `with` никак не меняет своё поведение из-за `with`

Comment: очень благодарен вам

Comment: Новый `urls_list` создаётся потому, что вы ему что-то присвоили, не объявив его как `global`, поэтому он стал локальным. Правильно это или нет - судить вам. В данном случае вы его заполняете из `sql`, глобальная переменная вам не нужна тут мне кажется.

Comment: да ненужна , я просто назвал её глобальной потому что не знал как еще назвать , и там слово глобальная в кавычках . Я прекрасно понимаю что здесь не нужна глобальная переменная

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку мои предположения из комментариев оказались верными, оформлю в ответ.

`sql.fetchall()` видимо возвращает список кортежей вроде такого:

```
[('http://url1',), ('http://url2',), ('http://url3',), ('http://url4',), ...]
```

В результате ваш слайс работает с кортежем, а не со строкой. А поскольку в кортеже всего один элемент, то слайс `[3:...]` возвращает пустой кортеж. Чтобы добраться до строки в первом элементе кортежа можно сделать так:

```
x[0][3:len(x[0])-4]
```

Но вообще с `URL` лучше работать с помощью специальных модулей библиотек, например `urllib.parse`, там есть методы для корректного разбиения `URL` на части. Это лучше и стандартнее, чем использовать слайсы.

Насчёт глобальной переменной: лучше вообще не использовать глобальные переменные. Хотите что-то передать в функцию - передавайте через аргументы функции. Хотите получить результат работы функции - передавайте его прозрачно - через `return`. Если вам нужно вернуть несколько разных объектов из функции - верните их через запятую и "распакуйте" результат вызова функции в несколько переменных, в питоне это очень удобно организовано.